# Install Valgrind on a target PowerPC machine

Tags: installation, valgrind, cross-compiling

I have the latest `Valgrind` source code. I want to install `Valgrind` on a target machine(`powerpc`) which has no support for building any softwares. So i will need to cross compile `Valgrind` on my build machine(x86) for the powerpc machine. Now my question is `how to install the cross compiled Valgrind` on to my target machine?

Answer (score 7):

To use valgrind's default tool(memcheck) on PPC, files needed are:

- ./coregrind/valgrind
- ./coregrind/vgpreload_core-ppc32-linux.so
- ./memcheck/memcheck-ppc32-linux
- ./memcheck/vgpreload_memcheck-ppc32-linux.so
- ./default.supp

After cross-compilation, copy these files to the same directory and launch `valgrind` on target with  `VALGRIND_LIB` set to where they are .

For example, if all files were copied into /tmp,

```
VALGRIND_LIB=/tmp /tmp/valgrind /PATH/TO/DEBUGGEE
```

will start DEBUGEE with valgrind.